# Replace words in a string based on starting letter of each word

Tags: ruby

I have a simple Ruby script that reads in data from a file, line by line this is a sample of the data;

```
"SW02 CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) V1000 V0020"
"T001 T665 CAR99A B0932 S222 LA44 V1009 V0029"
```

I'm trying to find a way to match and replace the entire word based on the first letter of each word. eg. 'Sxxxxxx' should be replaced with the word 'SWT', 'Vxxxx' replaced with 'VAL'

I expect an output of;

```
"SWR CAR BOT BOT BOT VAL VAL"
"TNK TNK CAR BOT SWT LTC VAL VAL"
```

Sample code;

```
File.open('test.txt').each do |line|
output = line.gsub!('V', 'VAL')
puts output
```

Is what I've tried so far (Which obviously doesn't work as it replaces any instance of V with VAL)

This is to automate a process to generate machine readable config files.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you are want to do. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex:

```
File.open('test.txt').each do |line|
  output = line.gsub!(/\bV[^\s]*/, 'VAL')
  puts output
end
```

EDIT:

For multiple replacing I suggest use hash instead of something like `case-when` and build regexp like below:

```
replacements = { 'V' => 'VAL', 'S' => 'SWT' }
str = "SW02 CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) V1000 V0020"
str.gsub(/\b(V|S)[^\s]*/) {|s| replacements[$1] }
#=> "SWT CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) VAL VAL"
```

Comment: That worked but it appears to be ignoring things (for example) in brackets. So from my quick test with `(/B\w+/, 'BAN')` gives me `BAN(A)` where it should just be 'BAN` Any ideas?

Comment: @user3788685, I've updated my answer. Please, update your question too for more clarity

Comment: Many thanks :) I shall try and learn up on regex - I did have a play about with a couple of on-line sites but there where not much help. I need to run some more tests on bigger more complex datasets but this appears to work.

Comment: @user3788685 a word character (`\w`) doesn't match `(` or `)`

Comment: @user3788685, you are welcome. Sure, regex is very powerful instrument, so it makes sense to learn it deeper.

Comment: Do you have any good guides/reference sites? Most of the ones I've seen show lots of code, but dont explain much/any of it.

Comment: @user3788685, you can read [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you want to map several values per line, i am not sure you want to use gsub for this.  Here is an example using map.  You can add any number of cases to the statement.

contents of test.txt

```
SW02 CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) V1000 V0020
T001 T665 CAR99A B0932 S222 LA44 V1009 V0029
```

parser

```
results = File.open('test.txt').each.map do |line|
  mapped_line = line.split.map  do |w|
  case w
  when /^S/
    "SWT"
  when /^V/
    "VAL"
  else
    w 
  end
end
mapped_line.join " "
end
puts results
```

Comment: A quick test with your code threw errors, but due to the output requirement and other things I'm doing in the script not shown here the `gsub!` method has worked so far and doesn't break anything upstream.

Comment: what error are you getting?  I ran this and it worked fine.

Comment: undefined method `each' for "\"R101A* R101B R103A* R103B R106A* R106B* R106C-1* R106C-2*\"\n":String (NoMethodError) My data may look like an array but it's not. It's just formatted that way for a machine readable situation.

Comment: I updated my answer to read from a file.   The idea was to show you how to process each line so the lines array was basically test data rather than actually reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBS = { "S"=>"SWT", "C"=>"CAR", "B"=>"BOT", "V"=>"VAL", "T"=>"TNK", "L"=>"LTC" }

def sub(str)
  str.gsub(/[A-Z0-9\(\)]+/i) { |word| SUBS[word[0]] }
end

sub "SW02 CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) V1000 V0020"
  #=> "SWT CAR BOT BOT BOT BOT VAL VAL" 
sub "T001 T665 CAR99A B0932 S222 LA44 V1009 V0029"
  #=> "TNK TNK CAR BOT SWT LTC VAL VAL"
```

This returns a new string, leaving the original string unchanged. If you wish to alter the existing string use `gsub!` rather than `gsub`.

A variant of this is to create an empty hash with a default block and then use that hash as a second argument for `gsub`:

```
SUBS = Hash.new do |h,k|
  case k[0]
  when "S" then "SWT"
  when "C" then "CAR"
  when "B" then "BOT"
  when "V" then "VAL"
  when "T" then "TNK"
  when "L" then "LTC"
  end
```

end

```
def sub(str)
  str.gsub(/[A-Z0-9\(\)]+/i, SUBS)
end

sub "SW02 CAR03 B0932 B23(B) B32(A) V1000 V0020"
  #=> "SWT CAR BOT BOT BOT BOT VAL VAL" 
sub "T001 T665 CAR99A B0932 S222 LA44 V1009 V0029"
  #=> "TNK TNK CAR BOT SWT LTC VAL VAL"
```

See the doc [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Comment: My data may look like an array, but its not. It's just formatted that way for later processing. so at the moment .gsub! is working